# Multiple time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I want to look at the effect of different environmental variables like temperature, precipitation, salinity on abundance of species and I have annual time series data for each variables. So, how can I use **ARIMA (autoarima)** or **VAR model** using R as I want to evaluate the accuracy of the model using mean average prediction error.

I want to use like:

```
model<- auto.arima( )
yhat<- predict(model, test$Abundance)
MAE<- mean(yhat$pred- obs)
```

My data look like:

```
Year     Abundance      P(mm)        T(oC)          Sal
1982    20.378          226.1515    6.52562637  31.2030989
1983    45.2278         465.9276    7.34045946  31.0757189
1984    25.3463         371.4884    7.62148182  31.2759091
1985    24.6418         357.211      5.9244     31.3786
1986    79.2654         128.2234    5.4179596   31.4520606
1987    49.6146         156.4768    6.258725    31.316825
1988    94.9638         401.7293    6.86823     31.19593
1989    84.3004         221.0092    6.36349296  31.185216
```

Comment: Can you clarify: Are you just trying to predict the abundance, not the other metrics?

Comment: @SkanderH, that is right! I am just trying to predict the abundance taking the other variables into consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your post what you are trying to achieve exactly:

**(a)** Are you looking to model the abundance this way:

$$abundance[Y_n]=f(environmentvars[Y_{n}])$$
 e.g the abundance of *1989* is based on the P(mm), T(oC), and           Sal of *1989* (and the *1988* abundance on the environmental vars of *1988*, etc...)?

**(b)** Or are you looking to model the effects of the abundance this way: 
$$abundance[Y_n]=f(environmentvars[Y_{n-1}])$$

e.g the abundance of *1989* is based on the P(mm), T(oC), and           Sal of *1988* (and the *1988* abundance on the environmental vars of *1987*, etc...)?

- If it is **(a)** you are after, then I would first try a regression model which outputs the abundance of each year based on the environmental variables of that same year, without any time series component. Then I would try a [Nowcasting](http://people.ischool.berkeley.edu/~hal/Papers/2013/pred-present-with-bsts.pdf) approach. Nowcasting refers to using forecasting techniques that are normally used to predict future values to predict present values - "Now" variables - instead. This is useful when a variable has a value now in the present, but measuring that variable is complicated and takes along time (e.g. economic variables such as unemployment or household income, etc...). So we treat the present value as an unknown that can be predicted using a time series model that includes external regressors. You can definitely use [ARIMAX](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) for this, it would look something like this (I'm omitting the [MA](https://otexts.com/fpp2/MA.html) terms for clarity, but please assume they are there as well): $$abundance[Y_n]=f(environmentvars[Y_{n}])+\phi_{n-1}abundance[Y_{n-1}]+\phi_{n-2}abundance[Y_{n-2}]+...$$ You need to be careful though, `auto.arima()` doesn't implement ARIMAX, it uses regression with ARMA errors, which is a different type of model, and I don't know if regression with ARMA errors can be used for Nowcasting or not (it might be, I'm just not sure). You might want to look at the Python package Statsmodels, which implements ARIMAX in the [SARIMAX module](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html). Better still, ditch the ARIMA family and try using [BSTS](http://www.unofficialgoogledatascience.com/2017/07/fitting-bayesian-structural-time-series.html) or [STS](https://medium.com/tensorflow/structural-time-series-modeling-in-tensorflow-probability-344edac24083), which are also good for Nowcasting.
- If it is **(b)** you are after, meaning you want to forecast *future* abundance using *current* environmental variables, then ARIMAX, or any time series model which includes external regressors is not a suitable choice, because for those approaches to work, you need to have good future estimates of the environmental variables (you might have good estimates for those over the next few days, but AFAIK you can't have reliable future forecasts for those for the next year). So your only option is to use a [VAR model](https://otexts.com/fpp2/VAR.html), which will give you something along the lines of (using VAR(1) for clarity, but this applicable to any VAR(n) model): $$abundance[Y_n]= \phi_1abundance[Y_{n-1}]+\psi_1P(mm)[Y_{n-1}]+\theta_1T(oC)[Y_{n-1}]+\eta_1Sal[Y_{n-1}]$$ You might be able to use other vector time series models, like Vector Exponential Smoothing, or Multivariate LSTM, but try VAR first.

To summarize: auto.arima is unlikely to work in your use case. If you are trying to achieve (a), then use SARIMAX or BSTS to implement a Nowcasting model. If you are trying to achieve (b), then you should use a vector time series model like VAR. Please note that if the only data you have is the data displayed in the OP, then none of these methods will work well, because they are all data hungry, and a sample size of 8 won't cut it, you should look for a simpler approach.

Comment: H, thank you very much! I was looking for case b, VAR and the data given above is just part of the whole data, I have multiple time series data. I want to fit the model and compute mean prediction error (mean (observed - predicted)), Is it possible to you to give me the highlight for the R code?

Comment: This [document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf) has the details you need. If you have code specific issues, as opposed to stats and modeling questions, you should post them in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com), not here. This forum is more for statistical and theoretical questions.